# ZF2 for RESTful API and pages in the same application

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm new to ZF and I'm kinda confused with something: I want to create an API (RESTful) with OAuth2 for authentication, and I want to serve pages that has Angular to consume that API. How is it possible to create an API and serve pages at the same time in ZF?
What is the best way to create an API in ZF? I read a little bit about apigility but it seems to create a lot of files and also an admin panel and I wanted to keep the project as clean as possible.
How to make versions of the API, like V1, V2?

Answer (score 1):

I was asking myself the same question some weeks ago. I needed a easy to use API implementation for a mayor ZF2 project.
After trying out different API "frameworks/modules" I ended up using Apigility. 
Apigility allows you to do a ton of stuff while keeping everything you need to set it up within configuration files.

To keep a better overview of the config files I just split them up having a foo.endpoint.api.config.php that only holds endpoint relevant data.

Apigility also allows integration for authentication.

As for the versioning. If I am not mistaken it also offers some module that helps you handle this. But at the end, if you want to have V1, V2, etc... this could be done via routes inside your config.

Note: You dont have to use the admin panel of apigility. In fact I didnt use it at all for my project, favoring the usage of the config directly.

Comment: I can only second that - Apigility provides many advanced features out of the box and some further features are easily enabled (Content Type Negotiation, API versioning, Authorization ...). It creates ~5 files per API, which is probably less than what you would end up manually. Although you should worry about the files involved last. The admin area is only enabled in dev production by default. I use it only to scaffold an API and than adjust everything manually in the code. The learning courve is quite high though and you should spend some time reading the code, it's quite unterstandable.

Comment: Thank you guys, it helped me a lot, sometimes it's nice to hear other people experiences in order to make a move. I was really confused about that.
@MethorZ you said you didn't used the admin area, how is that?

Comment: Yes... I am not a fan of fancy UI's. And I found the admin panel to be a bit heavy for my own taste. Too much "magic" happening in the background (creating files, folders, etc)... so I just didnt make use of it.

Instead I created my own structure in terms of folders and configs. Kind of like to be in control of stuff (:
Check this out, watch the code, should be a good way to get into the topic and how to use it: https://github.com/n1te1337/apigility-blog-example